# Issues converting json to csv with Python

Tags: python, json, csv

I can't figured out how to get the number values into a csv file in a col2 from the json file below. All I get is VAL1, VAL2, and VAL3 (see csv file sample at the end). I would like to get the json data like it is showing right below this text in the csv output file. Thank you so much for your help.

```
COL1,COL2
VAL1,123.777
VAL2,456.888
VAL3,789.999
```

*file.json*

```
{
    "success": true,
    "timestamp": 1663273564,
    "source": "ABC",
    "quotes": {
        "VAL1": 123.777,
        "VAL2": 456.888,
        "VAL3": 789.999
    }
}
```

*Python export code:*

```
import json
import csv
with open("C:file.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    
fname = "c:/output.csv"

with open(fname, "w") as file:
    csv_file = csv.writer(file)
    csv_file.writerow(["COL1","COL2"])
    for item in data["quotes"]:
        csv_file.writerow([item[0:4]])
```

*output.csv file*

```
COL1,COL2
VAL1
VAL2
VAL3
```

Comment: try `for item in data["quotes"].items():` that should get you closer...

Comment: And then `csv_file.writerow(item)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not about json or csv it's about working with dictionaries

```
a = {
    "success": True,
    "timestamp": 1663273564,
    "source": "ABC",
    "quotes": {
        "VAL1": 123.777,
        "VAL2": 456.888,
        "VAL3": 789.999
        }
    }

for i in a['quotes']:               # - the thing you have
    print([i[0:4]])
#output:                
    # ['VAL1']
    # ['VAL2']
    # ['VAL3']


for k,v in a['quotes'].items():     # - the thing you need to have  
    print(k,v)
#output:                
    # VAL1 123.777
    # VAL2 456.888
    # VAL3 789.999
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use your approach, the for loop will return one dictionary key at a time. You can then use this to look up the associated value as follows:

```py
import json
import csv

with open("file.json") as f_input:
    data = json.load(f_input)
    
fname = "output.csv"

with open(fname, "w", newline="") as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(["COL1","COL2"])
    
    for key in data["quotes"]:
        csv_output.writerow([key, data["quotes"][key]])
```

Alternatively, you can use `.items()` to return both the key and the value in the loop, giving you:

```py
import json
import csv

with open("file.json") as f_input:
    data = json.load(f_input)
    
fname = "output.csv"

with open(fname, "w", newline="") as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(["COL1","COL2"])
    
    for key, value in data["quotes"].items():
        csv_output.writerow([key, value])
```